# I've changed game systems, can I reask my favourite questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, game-systems

I got into RPing while D&D 4e was waning in popularity, so on the advice from my FLGS, picked up the Pathfinder Beginner Box. Had fun with it for a few years and got some great answers and help on RPG.SE.
Being the impressionable and fickle creature that I am, I've moved to D&D 5e, so I can play with the Underdark and Strahd.

Now that I'm using a different system, is it politic to reask questions that have answers based on a particular system? e.g. [Any GM headaches or canon reasons not to let resurrected PCs fight their reanimated corpses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19429/any-gm-headaches-or-canon-reasons-not-to-let-resurrected-pcs-fight-their-reanima) What about different editions of the same system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have reason to believe that the answers to the new question might be different from the answers to the old one?  If so, sure, go ahead and ask it again.  It could be something as simple as:

> A couple of years ago, I asked [whether a resurrected player could end up fighting their own undead corpse in Pathfinder,](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19429/any-gm-headaches-or-canon-reasons-not-to-let-resurrected-pcs-fight-their-reanima) and the consensus was that it probably wasn't possible strictly by the rules.  Is that still true in D&D 5e, or can I finally run my epic player-vs-ex-player battle without having to bend the rules?

If you have specific reasons, besides your gut feeling, for expecting different answers (e.g. because some relevant wording in the rules is different), you may also want to mention those in your question.  In particular, if the answer turns out to be "no, it's still the same", explaining why you thought it might be different will let answerers specifically address those reasons.

Comment: Indeed. I'm going to try to answer any question myself before asking anything. The agnostic aspects of the answers will be the same. The rule aspects will be covered in the required books, so I may end up not having a question to answer.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, absolutely! If your old solutions don't work anymore with the new system or edition you're using, then it's quite reasonable to ask a new question about your new situation.

Comment: Perhaps worth emphasizing the **If**.  For any question that is game- or system-agnostic, there should be no need to reask it.

Comment: @DanHenderson Truly system agnostic questions are pretty rare! Often for a question that seems it, answers will have a certain set of gaming philosophies in mind (e.g. D&D but not Fate or Dungeon World) and games with other philophies won't find the answers relevant. I think sticking with "if the solutions don't work for the new system/edition" hits the right mark with regards to those.

Comment: Tangentially: I suspect, but have no evidence, that reasking by writing it from scratch rather than by copy-paste results in a better new question than otherwise.

Comment: @DanHenderson This is true, but D&D 5e and Pathfinder are not nearly as far apart as D&D 5e and Fate.

Comment: True, I suppose very few questions would be **fully** system-agnostic.  But there are certainly *some* 3.5e-tagged questions that do not need to be re-asked for one or more of: Pathfinder, 4e, 5e, and probably at least three or four that will even work for Space: 1889 or Gamma World.